# Azure DevOps Server build not triggering release-run

Tags: azure-devops

For some reason my build got deleted, so I re-created it with the same name.

Each of my builds triggers a release-run to start upon completion.  In this case, my release then had to be re-associated with the new package, but it is no longer being triggered after the build has finished, even though the trigger is still enabled.

I tried deleting and re-associating the Artifact with the release-run.  I even deleted the entire release-run and re-created it.  It is still not being triggered after the build has finished.

Is there a solution for this?

The one thing I have not tried is changing the name of my release and release-run to make them more distinct from the old broken ones.  I don't want to do this, but at this point it feels like the only option left.  All my other builds/release's and release-runs are still working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not going to be enough to just establish the build artifacts for the trigger. You will also need to enable the "continuous deployment" option and choose to filter on whatever branches you wish to include or choose the pull request trigger.

Comment: Continuous deployment is a term used for Pipelines, not releases.  I know Microsoft messed up the terminology badly in this newest version of Azure DevOps since both areas share the Pipeline terminology.

My pipelines (builds) are working correctly.  It is the Releases (testing/deployment) that are not triggering after a successful build.  The "Define the trigger that will start deployment to this stage" is set to "After release".

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to convey. I am literally referring to the section in the release pipeline where you click on the lightning bolt of the artifact and chose "continuous deployment trigger." from there, you can choose the branches you want to filter on that will allow a release to kick off. The "after release" that you are referring to is later in the stage. Both are necessary in order to work.

Comment: Ha, you're right, I missed that trigger.  I'll give that a try, thanks.